# How do I test association in rails controller with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rspec-rails

I have an article model which has many comments and the comment belongs to one article. this is my create method for comments_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]

  @comment.save
  redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
end
```

I want to know what's the best approach to test this action with rspec. and I want to know testing methods for association in controller at all.

thank you experts.

Comment: I'd do a feature spec for this, not a controller spec.

Comment: How? and Why?  and what about controller spec?

Comment: @j-dexx - Feature tests falls more into BDD than TDD, and IMO the latter is more critical.

Comment: @BroiSatse I get your point, in total I'd do a feature spec but have a controller spec to check redirection of a successful create or rendering template if there are errors.  I like checking the comment count in your answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your comment object within your tests using `assigns` method:

```
describe CommentsController, type: :controller
  let(:comment_params) {{ <correct params goes here>}}
  let(:article_id) { (1..100).sample }
  let(:create!) { post :create, comment: comment_params, article_id: article_id }

  it "creates new comment" do
    expect { create! }.to change { Comment.count }.by 1
  end

  it "assigns given comment to correct article"
    create!
    expect(assigns(:comment).article_id).to eq params[:article_id]
  end
end
```

The above is just a guideline, you will need to modify it depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this codes.
This code is using FactoryGirl.

factory_girl is a fixtures replacement with a straightforward definition syntax... https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl
Please add `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` to `Gemfile`.

```
 def create
   @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]

   if @comment.save
     redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
   else
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Comment successfully created" # or you want to redirect path
   end
 end

 describe "POST #create" do
   let(:article_id) { (1..100).sample }

   context 'when creation in' do
     it 'creates a new comment' do
       expect { post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment), article_id: article_id }.to change {
        Comment.count
       }.from(0).to(1)
     end

     it 'returns same article_id' do
       post :create,  comment: attributes_for(:comment), article_id
       expect(assigns(:comment).article_id).to eq(article_id)
     end
   end

   context 'when successed in' do
     before { post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment), article_id }

     it 'redirects article path' do
       expect(response).to redirect_to(Comment.last.article)
     end
   end

    context 'when unsuccessed in' do
     before { post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment), article_id }

     it 'does not redirect article path' do
       expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
     end
   end
 end
```

uhh, I am not English native speaker. so If `it`'s sentence is not natural, please modify sentences. :-(

Comment: No problem Mr. @Ahmad